# Define the bounded metric on $R$ by $\bar{d}=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ Define a subset which is closed and bounded but not compact

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-writing

Define the bounded metric on $R$ by $\bar{d}=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ Define a subset which is closed and bounded but not compact. (Explain why not compact)

Proof-trying.

$d(x,y)+d(y,z)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}+\frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(y,z)}$

$ \geq
 \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}+ \frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)} = \frac{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}$

$= 1-\frac{1}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)} \geq 1-\frac{1}{1+d(x,z)}$

$= \frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}=d (x,z)$

**How can I define a subset which is closed and bounded but not compact, may you help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb N$ is a closed and bounded set for this metric which is not compact. Open sets for this metric are same as those for the usual metric so closedness and compactness are same for the two metrics.

For showing that the two metrics has the same closed sets (hence same open/compact sets) just show that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ iff $|x_n-x| \to 0$

Comment: To show this: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Assume there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$,  $|x_n-x|\to 0$. So clearly we get $d(x_n,x)=\frac{|x_n-x|}{1+|x_n-x|}\to 0$ How can I show other direction?

Comment: Express the usual metric in terms of this metric.

Comment: @JamesEnsor $|x-y|=\frac {d(x,y)} {1-d(x,y)}$ so $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ implies $|x_n-x| \to 0$.